# Perl Regular Expression for extracting multi-line LaTeX chapter name

Tags: regex, perl, latex

I am having a hard time figuring out how to perform a regex substitution to clean up some text in a LaTeX file.  The LaTeX file looks like

```
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{{II} {The Chapter 
Title}}{II The Chapter Title}}
```

Annoyingly, this is a multi-line chapter declaration, and the new line can occur virtually anywhere.  I can't use the common `<>` idioms to just read the file line by line and perform the straight-forward regular expression.

Instead, I am trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.old     # In-place edit, backup as '.old'
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

my $filename = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILENAME";
my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;

$content =~ s|\\chapter\{.*\{[IVXLCDM]*\s*(.*)\}\}|\\chapter{$1}|gms;
path($filename)->spew_utf8($content);
```

However, the regular expression is far too greedy, and begins a match at the first `\chapter` declaration and ends it at the last `chapter` declaration.  All I want is to

1. remove the `\texorpdfstring`.
2. remove the roman numeral
3. remove the multiple appearances of the chapter title

so that my substitution on

```
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{{I} {The First 
Chapter}}{I The First Chapter}}

It was the best of times.

\chapter{\texorpdfstring{{II} {The Second 
Chapter}}{II The Second Chapter}}

It was the worst of times.
```

results in

```
\chapter{The First Chapter}

It was the best of times.

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

It was the worst of times.
```

What can I do now?

Edit:  I changed the demo text.

---

If I understood @zdim correctly, he wrote down the substitution without escaping the braces {}'s, to make it easier to validate.  Fair enough.  I tried @zdim's solution but it output:

```
\chapter{The First
Chapter}

It was the worst of times.
```

Comment: Can I recommend you click on the [regex] tag, then Learn More… https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info then go to one of the sandboxes, and try out your sample input with a regular expression you iteratively work on.

Comment: @dlamblin: thank you, I am trying one now.

Comment: The last, added part, exposes a careless bug in my answer, whereby the trailing `.*` matched (and removed!) all the rest.  Sorry about that (please leave a comment and tag the user when something like this happens; I accidentally noticed the addition to the question). I edited the answer and fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only have the shown pairs of `{...}`

```
s/\\chapter{\\texorpdfstring{{ .*? }\s*{ (.*?) }}\s*{.*?}}/\\chapter{$1}/gsx;
```

or

```
s/(\\chapter){\\texorpdfstring{{.*?}\s*{(.*?)}}\s*{.*?}}/${1}{$2}/gs;
```

where `${1}` (for `$1`) is needed for syntax, as `$1{...` would be interpreted as a value of `%1`.

Or, rather

```
s/\\chapter\K{\s*\\texorpdfstring{{.*?}\s*{(.*?)}}\s*{.*?}}/{$1}/gs
```

where the [`\K` form of lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) drops previous matches. I still leave `{` to retype for a possibly clearer replacement part.

Please sprinkle this with `\s*` where there may be spaces.

Also note the [Path::Tiny::edit_utf8](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm#edit,_edit_raw,_edit_utf8)

```
path($filename)->edit_utf8( sub { s/.../.../gs } );  # regex as above
```

which applies the anonymous sub to the slurped file, as opposed to `edit_lines`.

If the braced expressions can be nested more freely (say with `{\em ... }` and such) a far more systemic approach is needed.  See for example [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) and search for "nested delimiters."

---

Some regex resources

Perl documentation

- [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), a tutorial
- [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), a quick-start introduction
- [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), the full account of syntax
- [perlreref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html), a quick reference (its [See Also](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#SEE-ALSO) section is useful on its own)

Stackoverflow

- [Regex info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)   An entry portal with resources
- [Reference: What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4653379)  A gargantuan list of FAQs with links to SO posts
- [Learning Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/4653379)   An overview with a long list of resources at the end

[Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)