# Path::Tiny and regular expression substitution produces empty file

Tags: regex, perl

I am having the darnedest time with a bug.  I recently asked [Perl Regular Expression for extracting multi-line LaTeX chapter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509953/perl-regular-expression-for-extracting-multi-line-latex-chapter-name), and followed the advice to use a Perl regular expression tester until I'm satisfied with my regular expression.  I committed my code and was happy.

But now, when I run the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.old     # In-place edit, backup as '.old'
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

my $filename = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILENAME";
my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;

$content =~ s/chapter/addchap/g;

path($filename)->spew_utf8($content);
```

I end up with an empty file.  It is very strange -- variations of this substitution (like `s/\\chapter/\\addchap/g;`) fail with an empty file, but dissimilar substitutions, like `$content =~ s/ //g;` don't.  Even stranger, the `perl -i` flag isn't being respected either.  What the heck is going on?

Here is some sample input:

```
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{{I} {Into the
Primitive}}{I Into the Primitive}}

Buck did not read the newspapers, or he would have known that trouble
was brewing, not alone for himself,
```

---

I updated my code, per the answers, but I am still getting empty files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

my $filename = shift or die "Usage: $0 FILENAME";
my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;

$content =~ s/\\chapter/\\addchap/gs;

path($filename)->spew_utf8($content);
```

The thing I find really confusing is that some substitutions "work", like:

```
$content =~ s/the/thee/g;
```

but even

```
$content =~ s/ch//g;
```

fails with an empty file.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-i.old` from the first line?

Comment: @GrantMcLean: yes, per your answer.

Comment: I copy-pasted the code in your update and it works with the sample text you provide (copy-pasted into a file). Perhaps other bits in your real input change how the regex works?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want that `-i` flag and Path::Tiny at the same time. `-i` is putting perl into a mode where it's trying to open and replace the file *for* you. It's not compatible with opening the file and rewriting it yourself.

One option is simply to remove the `-i` flag; your code should work as-is (but it won't produce a backup file, and the file replace won't be atomic).

The other is to keep the `-i` flag, but replace the body of your code with

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
while (<>) {
    s/chapter/addchap/g;
    print;
}
```

(eliminating all of the Path::Tiny stuff). Perl will add the rest implicitly.

This is equivalent to the one-liner

```
perl -CSD -i.old -pe 's/chapter/addchap/g' somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`-i` command line option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*[_extension_]) on the first line of the script is probably causing this problem.  Try deleting that.

When invoked with `perl -i`, Perl wraps some code around your script to loop over each file named on the command-line; read each line into `$_` in turn; invoke your script (once for each line); collect whatever output your script prints to STDOUT and write it into a temporary file; then after the last line, rename the temporary file over the top of the original file.  This is called an "in-place edit".

This is particularly handy for 1-liners, because you don't need to write the boilerplate code to read the input from a file and write the output to a file - you just write the processing code.  In your case, you *have* written that boilerplate (using Path::Tiny) so both Perl's `-i` implementation *and* your script are reading the input file and writing the output file.  Since your script does not output anything to STDOUT, `-i` will end up producing an empty file.